# find's mtime and ctime options

Tags: find, timestamps

I just created a text-file yyy in my home-directory. I modified it both with `touch yyy` and edited it manually.

Then I wanted to find this file (and others) via:

```
find ~/ -type f -mtime 1 -ctime 1 | grep yyy
```

but yyy isn't displayed. In find's man it is written:

> -ctime n: File's status was last changed n*24 hours ago. ...
>
> -mtime n: File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago. ...

So my **first question** is:

Why isn't yyy found

My **second question** is:

Does changed file's status mean: Changed content of file & permissions of file & ...?

Does modified file's data mean: Changed content of file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, "modified file's data" (`mtime`) means that the content was modified. This date can be manually changed (e.g. with `touch`).

Yes, "changed file's status" (`ctime`) means that either the content was changed, or the file's metadata (permission, owner, etc). This can not be changed manually.

Example:

```
$ date > foo
$ ls -l --full-time foo; ls -lc --full-time foo     # Both times have changed
-rw-r--r-- 1 xhienne xhienne 29 2017-01-18 13:40:07.677161702 +0100 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 xhienne xhienne 29 2017-01-18 13:40:07.677161702 +0100 foo

$ chmod o-r foo
$ ls -l --full-time foo; ls -lc --full-time foo     # Only ctime has changed
-rw-r----- 1 xhienne xhienne 29 2017-01-18 13:40:07.677161702 +0100 foo
-rw-r----- 1 xhienne xhienne 29 2017-01-18 13:40:29.601161310 +0100 foo

$ date >> foo
$ ls -l --full-time foo; ls -lc --full-time foo     # Again, both times have changed
-rw-r----- 1 xhienne xhienne 58 2017-01-18 13:40:51.297160921 +0100 foo
-rw-r----- 1 xhienne xhienne 58 2017-01-18 13:40:51.297160921 +0100 foo
```

Your file is not found because your `find` predicates `-mtime 1` and `-ctime 1` search for a file that was modified yesterday (more exactly between 24h ago and 48h ago). For a file that is modified today, use either `-mtime 0` or `-mtime -1` (same for `-ctime`).

Example:

```
$ find -name foo -mtime 1 -ctime 1

$ find -name foo -mtime 0 -ctime 0
./foo

$ find -name foo -mtime -1 -ctime -1
./foo
```

Comment: Thanks, reading `atime` option explanation, it is written: `When find figures out how many 24-hour periods ago the file was last accessed, any fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to
              have been accessed at least two days ago.`

This means: -ctime 0 : within [now,now+24h]

-ctime +1 : within [now+2*24h,infinity];

-ctime -1 : within [now,now+2*24h];

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Right. I added a precision to my answer just before your comment. I believe you didn't see it. Is my answer still in need of an edit according to you?

Comment: @FloHe Yes except for `-ctime -1` which means less that 24h ago, that is with [now, now + 24h[

Comment: `-mtime -1` would also report files with modification time in the future, so it's not equivalent to `-mtime 0`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Right, and I didn't say they were equivalent. I just said that the OP can use either of them for their scenario.