# How to find files created one hours before?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I have the folder, the files will comning hourly daily in here. After that, i want to copy only files, which created date one hours before to other folder.
For example: Currently datetime is 9:20:00AM, I want to copy files with create date from 8:00:00AM to 8:59:59AM . I'm not familiar with shell linux.

```
#!/bin/bash
logfile="/usertest/log/"`date +"%Y%m%d"`.log
(
srcRoot=/usertest/source
destRoot=/usertest/dest
copyFile(){
    local src=$srcRoot/$1
    local dest=$destRoot/$2
    local now1=$(date)
    echo "Current date time " "$now1"
    echo src: $src
    echo dest: $dest
    #For example: current datetime is 2023-08-14 09:20:33 AM
    #find files created date from 2023-08-14 08:00:00AM to 08:59:59AM
    #copy files from source to destination
    #print message copy filename from source to dest
    find "$src" -mtime $(date +%H)-1 ":59:59" -mtime $(date +%H)-1 ":00:00" -exec cp -p {} "$dest" \;
    echo "copy from " "$src" "file name" "to" "$dest" "file name"
}
copyFile subfolder/folderx foldery
) >> $logfile 2>&1
```

Comment: AFAIK most linux filesystems do not store as meta information the creation time. And you search for modification time. So you should reconsider your requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the GNU `find` utility, which should be preinstalled on your system.

If you open a terminal, and navigate to the folder you want to search through (use `cd` for that), then the following finds all files under that directory, that have been created within the last hour.

```shell
find . -type f -newerct '1 hour ago'
```

When you replace the `-newerct` with `-newermt` it gives you all files modified within the last hour.

You can learn more about find when you type in `man find`, it has many cool options. Another one is the `-not` flag, which can be used to invert expressions.

Comment: This search for modification time, not creation time.

Comment: @RomeoNinov thanks, just noticed

Comment: `-newerct` compares the `c`time` (the change status time) with the given `t`ime. For the creation time where `-newermt`, where the last modification time can be seen as the date the contents was created (finished created) or `-newerBt` for the `B`irth time, though that timestamp is not supported everywhere and is not necessarily relevant depending on how those files are created.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The hint for simplifying the command is appreciated, newerBt does not work on my find. While changing the inode of a file might in theory be different from creation, in the normal case it's not, same thing for timezone ambiguities. Also, OP asked about Linux specifically, so I think GNU should be fine

Comment: In the normal case, the ctime is changed  whenever anything changes about a file including content and metadata (not atime), it has little to do with *creation*.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas interesting! After reading [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558124/understanding-find-with-atime-ctime-and-mtime) question, I assumed that ctime references the time the inode was last changed. But after looking at the man page I see that's wrong

Comment: So, i don't know we can combine like this ```current_hour=$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:00:00%z)
previous_current_hour=$(date -d "$current_hour -1 hour" +%FT%T%z)
find "$src" -mtime "$current_hour" ! -mtime "$previous_current_hour" -exec cp -p {} "$dest" \;```

Comment: @Headshot you forgot the `-t` flag, the `+` and you kind of mixed up the order, but the rest should work. Stephanes solution with specifying the target via the `-t` flag and with `+` is pretty elegant actually, because it copies everything in one go, and you don't need to worry about the `{}` replacement

Answer (score 2):

With any standard implementation of the `date` utility, the start of the current hour formatted in an unambiguous standard local time format can be obtained with:

```
this_hour_start=$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:00:00%z)
```

To get the timestamp one hour before that, with GNU `date`, you can do:

```
previous_hour_start=$(
  date -d "$this_hour_start -1 hour" +%FT%T%z
)
```

Once you have both, with GNU `find`, you can find regular files created (with contents last modified) during the previous hour with:

```
find . -type f \
       -newermt "$previous_hour_start" \
       ! -newermt "$this_hour_start"
```

And to copy them elsewhere, with GNU `cp`, add `-exec cp -t /elsewhere {} +` to the above command.

Comment: Wouldn't checking `-newerct` still be more robust than mtime? In the sense, that it's more likely that files have their contents changed than their permissions

Comment: But this is modification time , not created time, is it right ?, consider with ```-mtime``` command

Comment: @Fynn, the ctime is not the creation time, it's updated when mtime is uptdated as well. The mtime as checked by both `-mtime` and `-newermt` is generally the one you want as it's the time the contents was created (was finished being written). The birth/creation time which is the time the inode spawned into existence (not necessarily by the current path/name) is not always relevant/useful and `-newerBt` is less widely supported than `-newermt`.

Comment: my server not have ```-newerBt``` , only have ```-mtime```

Comment: @Headshot, `-mtime` `n`/`-n`/`+n` is to select files whose age rounded down to an integer number of days is `n` / less than `n` / more than `n`. It can't be used here. The `-newerXY` predicates are from BSD, and is also supported by GNU `find` (as found on most generic GNU/Linux distributions) and toybox find (Android) at least. Please clarify what system you're on and what implementation of `find` there is there. Birth/creation times are historically not used on Linux.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I understood that, but somehow I thought that status change exclusively refers to changing the file permissions. Welp, I should read more man pages and less weird stuff on the internet -.-
Thanks for explaining though