# find -cmin vs. find -mmin || status vs. data – What is the difference?

Tags: find

I'm learning the **find** command and trying out variations ..
Wondering what the actual difference is between `find ~ -cmin 1` and `find ~ -mmin 1`. 
Reading the man page, the difference comes down to file **status** vs file **data**. 
My tests have always shown the exact same results. 

What is the exact difference between both options? 
In which scenario would I use the one over the other?

#### man page entries:

**-cmin n** 
File's **status** was last changed n minutes ago. 

**-mmin n** 
File's **data** was last modified n minutes ago.

Comment: Related: [find's mtime and ctime options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338303/finds-mtime-and-ctime-options)

Comment: thanks, that answers the question.

Comment: Please note tat `-cmin` and `-mmin` are non-helpful and on-portable GNU extensions. Modern `find` implementations implement support for `-mtime -3m` for files that have been modified during the past 3 minutes and  `-mtime -5h` for files that have been modified during the past 5 hours.